# openbsd: limit network bandwidth

Tags: java, linux, openbsd

I have task:

"*Develop the program on JavaEE(simple web application using Servlet/JSP techlogies), that will be run on 'OpenBSD 5.6. amd64' server and that provides interface for controlling network ports(**up**/**down** and **limit speed**)*"

Up/Down is simple: ifup 'interface-name'/ifdown 'inteface-name'.

But with ***'limit speed'*** i have some difficulties.

I want do this with shal command, but i can't find sample.

Only with third-party tools: **Wondershaper**, **Trickle**.

Related topics: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth)

Any ideas?

In advance thanks for help!

Comment: If you just need to be able to set to 100BaseTX or 10BaseT, you can use the information [here](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Setup.if)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try and report.

Comment: This solution works, but i need set any speed value - not discrete((

Comment: In that case, you'll need to go with @Bink's answer. One product I know of that uses this method is pfSense's Captive Portal code.

Answer (score 0):

On OpenBSD, this is done using the built-in packet filter, which also performs bandwidth control.  I recommend starting with the pfctl(8) man page and reviewing the related ones as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try and report.

Comment: I read the manual, but it very hard. 
Also i can't find sample of usage that command.
You can more detail explain how it use?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://kestas.kuliukas.com/pf.conf/#NATQueueing) topic, but he a little complex. 
Tell me please, it that what I need?

Comment: This write up is very old and doesn’t cover a modern version of OpenBSD.  I recommend you review the Queueing section of pf.conf(5) man page and then ask a specific question related to that.