# openbsd: install program from .tar or .deb

Tags: java, linux, installation, openbsd

I have problem, that described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108069/openbsd-limit-network-bandwidth) topic.

But the proposed solutions are hard or not unsuitable for me.

There are one more solution - use third-party tools.

I will trying use **wondershaper** tool, but i cannot install it on OpenBSD server.

I found it as [.deb](http://www.filewatcher.com/_/?q=wondershaper%20openbsd) file or [.tar.gz](ftp://ftp.openbsd.dk/.disk1/debian/pool/main/w/wondershaper/) archive.

Search in google don't helped me.

Somebody, tell me please, is it possible or not make this(install this tool)?

In advance thanks for help!

Comment: I found this[ http://kestas.kuliukas.com/pf.conf/#NATQueueing ] topic, but he a little complex. 
Tell me please, it that what I need?

Answer (score 0):

wondershaper is a script which uses [tc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tc_%28Linux%29) which is a Linux command. It won't work on OpenBSD.

You did found those `.deb` and `.tar.gz` files on a FTP-Server named OpenBSD, because this are server which are mirrors for many software projects and are reachable under many different names.
If you look closely at those files, you will see that most of them have `debian` or `ubuntu` in their file path.